# Post values of a checkbox

Tags: php, post, checkbox

I have this code on my form for the checkboxs:

```
<input type="hidden" name="option_desc[]" value="option 1"/>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="option_price[]" value="10" class="option_checkbox"/>option 1</label>

<input type="hidden" name="option_desc[]" value="option 2"/>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="option_price[]" value="20" class="option_checkbox"/>option 2</label>

<input type="hidden" name="option_desc[]" value="option 3"/>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="option_price[]" value="30" class="option_checkbox"/>option 3</label>
```

I'm trying to get the POST values of the checkbox that the user checked (for example, if he checked the second checkbox: "option 2" + "20") and store them:

```
    $articleDetails['options'] = array();
$count = 0;
if(is_array($_POST['option_price'])){
    foreach($_POST['option_price'] as $key => $value){
        if($value){
            $articleDetails['options'][$count]['option_price'] = $_POST['option_price'][$key];
            $articleDetails['options'][$count]['option_desc'] = $_POST['option_desc'][$key];
            $count++;
        }
    }
}
```

When the user check one of the checkbox, the appropriate 'option_price' is stored correctly, but the 'option_desc' is not the one that belongs to the CHECKED checkbox (for example: when the second checkbox is checked the values that I get are "20" (GOOD) and "option 1" (NOT GOOD).

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: You'll want to put numbers in the [] in the html. If a checkbox is not checked, it is not submitted. So you can have different number of items in each array, and without defined keys they won't match up.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is that if checkboxes are not checked, the data won't get POSTed while your hidden inputs will always be posted. Frankly, I don't see what value your hidden inputs give you here. They tell you absolutely nothing about the posted data that you don't already know about on the server.

You should simply use a defined index in your array notation for the checkbox field, like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="option_price[1]" value="10" class="option_checkbox"/>option 1</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="option_price[2]" value="20" class="option_checkbox"/>option 2</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="option_price[3]" value="30" class="option_checkbox"/>option 3</label>
```

Note: I didn't use zero-indexed array here as I figured you might want to directly relate `$_POST['option_price'][1]` to "option 1".

To add some examples related to the discussion in comments below.  Say for example you had some `option_price` checkboxes you want to output, and they come from some dynamic source. Your code to to generate the checkboxes might look something like this:

```
$price_options = array(
    array(
        'description' => 'eBook',
        'value' => 10
    ),
    array(
        'description' => 'articles',
        'value' => 20
    ),
    // and so on
);

$count = count($price_options)
for($i = 1; $i<= $count; $i++) {
?>
<input type="checkbox" name="option_price[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="<?php echo $price_options[$i]['value']; ?>" class="option_checkbox"/><?php echo $price_options[$i]['description']; ?></label>
<?php
} // end for
```

When POSTing you know that every `$_POST['option_price'][x]` would correspond to the item at `$price_options[x]`.

You could simply iterate of `$_POST['option_price']` to see which items are selected like this:

```
if(!empty($_POST['option_price']) {
    foreach ($_POST['option_price'] as $index => $value) {
        // verify value hasn't been tampered with
        if ((int) $value === $price_options[$index]['value']) {
            // set description
            $description = $price_options[$index]['description'];
            var_dump($description, $value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But the options are not really "option 1", "option 2", etc. They varied... So how can I get these different values without the hidden inputs? (I can't use the value of the checkbox to store them). Thanks!!

Comment: Well you control the output of values to begin with.  Why do you then need to also have them posted back to you?  All you are doing is adding more fields against which you need to do input data validation/sanitization without those fields providing you with any additional information you did not already have when you served up the page. Why solicit input for information you already know?

Comment: If for example the first checkbox should have "eBook" as label and the second "articles" as label. How can I get these values?

Comment: @user3084703 Yes, but these are known values that you control.  You can either maintain an options to name map on the server (i.e. 1 => 'eBook', 2 => 'articles'), or you can even choose to use associate type of naming for your inputs e.g. `name="option_price[ebook]"` or `name="option_price[articles]"`.  Again the hidden inputs provide you with zero new information and just make your life harder in having to validate on the server.

Comment: So if I use `name="option_price[ebook]"`, how can I get the `ebook`? What should I write in the php code: 
`$articleDetails['options'][$count]['option_desc'] = $_POST['option_desc'][$key];`  insted of `$_POST['option_desc'][$key];`? Thanks!!

Comment: @user3084703 I added some additional commentary in my answer above to give you an idea of how to work with the POSTed data.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest give names to input like

```
<input type=hidden name="option[1][desc]"/> 
<input type=hidden name="option[1][price]"/>
```

Then I think it would be easy to run a forreach as well.